# How to cast correctly?

Tags: java, generics

```
protected final Class<? extends MyBaseClass>[] getClasses(){
    return new Class[]{
        MyClass1.class,
        MyClass2.class
    };
}
```

Now, as the dev, I know that `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` extends `MyBaseClass`, but how do I do it properly so that the IDE/compiler won't give warning?

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")      before method declaration

Answer (score 1):

You can't get there without suppressing warnings. You either have to deal with the compile-time error preventing the creation of an array of a generic type, or the current warning.

The closest alternative is to make your method return a collection type:

```
protected final List<Class<? extends MyBaseClass>> getClasses() {
    return Arrays.asList(MyClass1.class, MyClass2.class);
}
```